# Prove or disprove : the number $3+2\sqrt{-2}$ is irreducible in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Prove or disprove: the number $3+2\sqrt{-2}$ is irreducible in the
>   ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$.

I think it is sufficient to show that each element (except $0$) in $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{D}$ with $D \in \mathbb{Z}$ has a multiplicative inverse. So if I take the element $z=a+b\sqrt{D}$, the inverse $z^{-1}$ should be $\frac{\bar{z}}{\bar{z}z}$.

Am I right? Otherwise, is there anyone who could give me a hint to solve the problem?

Comment: You seem to be trying to prove is that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a field. This is false - for example $3$ is not invertible. Do you understand what "irreducible" means in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $3+2\sqrt{-2}=xy$. Then, using conjugates, you get
$$
(x\bar{x})(y\bar{y})=(3+2\sqrt{-2})(3-2\sqrt{-2})=17
$$
Then…

Note that an element $z$ is irreducible if it is not $0$, it is not invertible and, if $z=xy$, then either $x$ or $y$ is invertible.

Answer (score 3):

$N(3+2\sqrt{-2})=(3+2\sqrt{-2})(3-2\sqrt{-2})=17.$

If $3+2\sqrt{-2}=a\cdot b$, then $N(a)N(b) = N(ab) = 17$, thus wlog $N(a)=1$, hence $a$ is invertible.